# Get Substring between two characters in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, substring

I want to get the string between two characters in the following string:

```
hello @user1, how are you?
```

I want to get the text between the `@` and the `SPACE` after the `@` which results in `user1`, is there a way to do this? There could even be 2 or more `@` which I will need to extract like

```
hello @user1 ,@user2 ,@... , how are you?
```

here is a table-like example:

| Sample | Excpected Output |
| --- | --- |
| Hello @user1 and @user2 how are you? | user1, user2 |
| @user1 and @user2 replied | user1, user2 |

but there will always be a `SPACE` after each `@`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you share your input samples and expected output in a table-like format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to approach would be a combination of `String_Split()` and `String_Agg()`:

```
with sampledata as (
  select 'Hello @user1 and @user2 how are you?' sample union all
  select '@user1 and @user2 replied'
)
select sample, String_Agg(Replace([value], '@',''), ', ') Result
from sampledata
cross apply String_Split(sample,' ')
where [value] like '@%'
group by sample;
```

See [Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6470206349c5a3f5d3f25e29d3e4fe0a)

As requested, a possible alternative approach to ensure the ordering of the string elements is as follows; this method uses a *json array* that provides the array index for ordering:

```
select sample, 
  String_Agg(Replace([value], '@',''), ', ') within group(order by seq) Result
from sampledata
cross apply (
  select j.[value], 1 + Convert(tinyint, j.[key]) Seq 
  from OpenJson(Concat('["', replace(sample, ' ', '","'), '"]')) j
)s
where [value] like '@%'
group by sample;
```

Note from [this alternative Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=881e6b856c9751f20786b8a87169a969) you can reverse the ordering or the strings using the *desc* keyword.

Comment: Neither string_agg or string_split guarantee order - which might be important.

Comment: String_agg has *within group order by* but string_agg until 2022 does not, this is true. (although in actual use I've never seen it fail) If string order is important there are alternative methods, if the OP would care to clarify if it's the case I would be happy to offer alternative.

Comment: @Stu In this case, order of the extracted string doesn't really matter that much, but if you can answer the question with an alternative solution I would appreciate it, just in case somebody else needs it. Thank you

Comment: @AIDENIV As requested see my edit for an alternative string_split that guarantees the order.